# how to push into nested array in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers

[image]

Above image shows what happens when I trying to dispatch a reply action.

Currently trying to push the input field value etc into the replyComments...but it is still empty even when dispatching this action.... the reducer is checking the majorIndex first and then the minorIndex, from there it should push it into the replyComments. Any one knows how I can fix this?

[Link to working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu/instagram-redux)

```js
 case types.REPLY_COMMENT: {
            return {
                ...state,
                enableToggleComment: true,
                imageData: state.imageData.map(image => image.id === action.majorIndex ?
                    {   
                        ...image, 
                        comments: {
                            [action.minorIndex]: {
                                replyComments: [...image.comments.replyComments, { comment: action.newComment, likeComment: image.toggle, enableReply: false }]
                            }
                        }
                        } : image
                    )
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Currently trying to push the input field value etc into the replyComments...but without any success` .... *without any success* is not helpful. Its implied as you are indeed posting on SO. What is your actual error or exception message? Also im not seeing any code related to a "push". All you are showing is a data structure.

Comment: i want to push it into replyComments array....the only thing that you have to look at is the ...image.comments.replyComments.....that is the part which is not working yet....

Comment: Is `image.id === action.majorIndex` ever `true` ? Are you sure you're comparing the same data types (number with number, string with string, etc.) ?

Comment: yes image.id === action.majorIndex is true

Comment: try building the structure in a variable before the `return` statement so you can `console.log` the values and see what's going on.

Comment: In the image, `comments` is an array but in the code you treat it like an object `comments: {..}` and since in the image `comments` is still an array, the `image.id === action.majorIndex` condition was probably never `true` (that property's value was never changed to an `object`).

Comment: What `minorIndex` is used for? also there is no `newComment` in the action

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I know noticed it's due to a missing key to `[action.minorIndex]` and when using the `?` operator and want to return an object you should add the parenthesis, otherwise you are declaring a scope (like i did whoops)

```
case types.REPLY_COMMENT: {
            return {
                ...state,
                enableToggleComment: true,
                imageData: state.imageData.map(image => image.id === action.majorIndex ?
                    ({   
                        ...image, 
                        comments: {
                            [action.minorIndex]: {
        replyComments: [...image.comments[action.minorIndex].replyComments, { comment: action.newComment, likeComment: image.toggle, enableReply: false }],
                            }
                        }
                    }) : image
                )
            }
        }
```

Comment: when i do this it shows 'replyComments is undefined'

Comment: i've edited my reply. I'ts totally a different answer. Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

I've only added `action.replyText` but you should be able to add the rest now

```js
case types.REPLY_COMMENT: {
    return {
        ...state,
        enableToggleComment: true,
        imageData: state.imageData.map(image =>
            image.id === action.generalIndex
            ? {
                ...image,
                comments: image.comments.map((comment, i) =>
                    i === action.majorIndex
                    ? {
                        ...comment,
                        replyComments: [
                            ...comment.replyComments,
                            action.replyText
                        ]
                    }
                    : comment
                )
            }
            : image
        )
    };
}
```